# Comparing standard deviations over different product categories

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have sentiment data (a column with floats between 0 and 1) from online customer reviews. The products are divided into product categories. How can I calculate the standard deviation for each product category?

I did a calcualted column like this:

```
stddev = STDEV.P(customer_reviews[sentiment])
```

But that gives me the standard deviation for the whole population with all product categories. How to I also take into consideration (group by?) the product category (customer_reviews[product_category])?

What I'm trying to see is if different product categories have different standard deviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your table looks something like this:

[image]

You could convert the formula you have to a maesure and use it in a matrix-visual with `customer_reviews[product_category]` on rows. Like so:

[image]

For a calculated column you could use this:

```
Column_stddev =
CALCULATE (
    STDEV.P ( customer_reviews[sentiment] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'customer_reviews', customer_reviews[product_category] )
)
```

[image]